# std::bind works with decltype type of class member functions failed

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I am using decltype and std::remove_pointer to declare type class, and want to pass it to std::bind.

```
class Result { 
public:
    Result(){}
    ~Result(){}
    std::string get(const std::string& name) { return name; } 
}; 

typedef std::function<std::string()> MyGet; 

int main() {
    // OK
    Result result1;
    MyGet mg1 = std::bind(&Result::get, &result1, std::cref("result1"));
    std::cout << mg1() << std::endl;
    // OK
    Result result2;
    MyGet mg2 = std::bind(&decltype(result2)::get, &result2, std::cref("result2"));
    std::cout << mg2() << std::endl;
    // Failed
    Result* result3 = new Result;
    MyGet mg3 = std::bind(&decltype(std::remove_pointer(result3))::get, &result3,
std::cref("result3"));
    std::cout << mg3() << std::endl;
    delete result3;

    return 1; 
}
```

the result3 part of code show this error:
cannot refer to class template 'remove_pointer' without a template argument list
how to fix it?

Comment: Just curious: why have you chosen `std::bind` instead of using a lambda?

Comment: `std::remove_pointer` operates on types, not expressions (which is why the syntax is `typename std::remove_pointer<SomeType>::type`, not `std::remove_pointer(SomeExpression)`.

Comment: do you mean the result3 is SomeExpression? this is also build failed:MyGet mg3 = std::bind(&std::remove_pointer(Result*)::type::get, &result3, std::cref("result3"));

Comment: To use a lambda: `auto mg1 = [result1] () { return result1.get ("result1"); };` and declare `get` `const`.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `remove_pointer` to get the type that `result1` points to when you already know that type?  It's simply `Result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your last `std::bind` call:

- `std::remove_pointer(result3)`

`remove_pointer` is a class. You want `remove_pointer_t` which will produce the type sans pointer in parentheses, which leads to the next point

- `result3` is an *instance* of `Result*`, we need to use `decltype` to get its type, because `remove_pointer` operates on type, which leads to the next point:
- `std::remove_pointer` as a templated type trait wants a *type* as a *template argument* in angle braces, not in parentheses

With the edits applied this bring us to the following syntax

```
MyGet mg3 = std::bind(&std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(result3)>::get, result3, std::cref("result3"));
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h3tGoKfV6c2ue0Hc)

---

In the end, a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) may be easier to deal with. You don't need to construct a `std::function` at all:

```
Result result1;
auto mg1 = [&result1](){return result1.get("result1");};
std::cout << mg1() << std::endl;
Result result2;
auto mg2 = [&result2](){return result2.get("result2");};
std::cout << mg2() << std::endl;
Result* result3 = new Result;
auto mg3 = [result3](){return result3->get("result3");};
std::cout << mg3() << std::endl;
delete result3;
```

[Lambda demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3feYkT9QQZh6jL57)

I highly recommend [STL's CppCon 2015 talk](https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?t=1518) about why `bind()` is all but deprecated in favor of lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
Result* result3 = new Result;
MyGet mg3 = std::bind(
    &std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(result3)>::get, result3, std::cref("result3"));
```

or

```
MyGet mg3 = std::bind(
    &std::remove_pointer<decltype(result3)>::type::get, result3, std::cref("result3"));
```

`std::remove_pointer` operates on types, not expressions. Use `decltype` to get the type of `result3` and then remove the pointer.

Also, you should of course pass `result3` directly, not a pointer to it (it is already a pointer).

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Rf2PpB

Comment: But we already know the type of `remove_pointer<decltype(result3)>` ... it's `Result`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely We also already know what the program will output, yet we went throug the `std::bind` song and dance. The implicit assumption here was that the type of `result3` is not known beforehand and just presented this way for simplicity. I'm aware that this would probably involve templates so there would be some `typename` shenanigans (which is another good reason to use lambdas instead).

Comment: in the second option(meant for c++11), isn't `std::remove_pointer<decltype(result3)>::type::get` should have `typename`, as `::type` is depended?

Comment: @JeJo Only if we are in a template function. `main` is not a template function so there is no two-phase lookup and no dependent names. But as mentioned above, it's unlikely that you need `std::remove_pointer` outside of a template, which is why this code looks weird.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Oh.. yeah. I didn't read the comments and went for the answers. BTW, I didn't know about this too!

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `decltype` on the variable to get the type at first, and then use `remove_pointer` to get the type you want.
2. `result3` is a pointer itself, you should pass `result3` or `*result3` instead of `&result3`.

e.g.

```
MyGet mg3 = std::bind(&std::remove_pointer<decltype(result3)>::type::get, result3, std::cref("result3"));
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `*result3` would store a copy inside the bind result, which might not be what's intended (it's not what the previous two uses of `bind` in the OP's code do, anyway).